# ANDROID FACEBOOK SDK-4.0: I get an error when i use "/me?fields=age_range" in my GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest

Tags: android, facebook, graph, android-facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

1. I need to get the `age_range` from facebook.
2. When i use `/me?fields=age_range` in my `GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest` i get an error.
3. The error is that `graphObject` returns `null`. I've tried using `/me` and it works i get the correct user data though when i use `/me?fields=age_range` i get this error.

> Testing﹕ {Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 2500, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.}}

---

This is the code i've been trying to fix.

```
         GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(accessToken,
                        "/me?fields=age_range",
                        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {

                                Log.v("Testing", graphResponse.toString());


                            }
                        });
                request.executeAsync();
```

Comment: Where do you get the `AccessToken` from? Is the user actually logging in and is your Facebook app approved by Facebook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not put "/me?fields=age_range" as the path in your GraphRequest.

Instead, only use "/me" as the path, and then create a new Bundle, and put "fields" as the key, and "age_range" as a string value, and set the new bundle as the parameters on the GraphRequest.

```
GraphRequest request = ...
...
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("fields", "age_range");
request.setParameters(params);
request.executeAsync();
...
```

Comment: Worked for me too. I'm developing with Xamarin. Thanks.